# Quantstrat dynamic order sizing in percents

Tags: r, quantstrat

I want to set order size not in absolute values in lots or dollars but in percents. E.g. I set ordersize <- 0.3 and then the necessary number of lots is calculated as 30% of current equity. Should I use [osMaxPos](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/quantstrat/versions/0.14.6/topics/osMaxPos) / [osMaxDollar](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/IKTrading/versions/1.0/topics/osMaxDollar) or write a custom sizing function somehow?

```
add.rule(
  strategy.st, name = 'ruleSignal',
  label = 'EnterLONG', type = 'enter',
  arguments = list(
    sigcol = signal$long$enter$label, sigval = TRUE,
    replace = TRUE, orderset = 'ocolong', orderqty = 1,
    ordertype = 'market', orderside = 'long'
  )
)
add.rule(
  strategy.st, name = 'ruleSignal',
  label = 'ExitLONG', type = 'exit',
  arguments = list(
    sigcol = signal$long$exit$label, sigval = TRUE,
    replace = TRUE, orderset = 'ocolong', orderqty = 'all',
    ordertype = 'market', orderside = 'long'
  )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those as excited as i am, here's a solution:

I found a perfect beginning in creating custom order sizing function [here](https://timtrice.github.io/backtesting-strategies/trailing-stops.html#osfixeddollar), Tim Trice referenced to [comments section](https://quantstrattrader.wordpress.com/2014/09/24/nuts-and-bolts-of-quantstrat-part-iv/) in Ilya Kipnis' blog. Also i found out that a portfolio needs to be updated to get actual equity in a [Joshua Ulrich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494187/r-quantstrat-how-to-make-a-transaction-for-complete-equity-in-portfolio).

```
leverage <- 10 # 1:10
tradeSize <- 0.3 # 30%
osFixedPercent <- function(timestamp, orderqty, portfolio, symbol, ruletype, ...) {
  if(!exists("tradeSize")) stop("You must set trade size")

  updatePortf(portfolio)
  portfolio <- getPortfolio(portfolio)
  equity <- initEq + sum(portfolio$summary$Period.Realized.PL)

  ClosePrice <- as.numeric(mktdata[timestamp,]$close)
  maxPos <- equity * tradeSize
  initialMargin <- ClosePrice / leverage
  orderqty <- sign(orderqty) * floor(maxPos / initialMargin)

  return(orderqty)
}
```